# I want to add awk command result to end of each rows in a csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have files as below:

InputFile.csv:

```
"Input_File:",AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,,,,
"Date_Time Received:","1-28-22 3:47",,,,
1, abc, xyz,pq,11
2, def, xyz,rs,22
3, ghi, xyz,tu,33
4, jkl, xyz,vw,44
5, mno, xyz,xy,55
```

OutputFile.csv:

```
1, abc, xyz,pq,11,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
2, def, xyz,rs,22,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
3, ghi, xyz,tu,33,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
4, jkl, xyz,vw,44,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
5, mno, xyz,xy,55,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
```

I am getting file_name & date_time from `awk` command and storing as below:

```
file_name=`awk -F',' 'NR==1{print $2}' InputFile.csv`
date_time=`awk -F',' 'NR==2{print $2}' InputFile.csv`
```

What I need is for the captured file_name and date_time to be added as last 2 columns for each row.

Please help me achieve this output format.

Comment: Please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers to learn what to do next with this question and then do what it says there.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F'"?,"?' -v OFS=',' 'NR<3{a[NR]=$2; next} {print $0, a[1], a[2]}' InputFile.csv
1, abc, xyz,pq,11,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
2, def, xyz,rs,22,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
3, ghi, xyz,tu,33,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
4, jkl, xyz,vw,44,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
5, mno, xyz,xy,55,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
```

and if anyone wants to play golf (inspired by a now-deleted comment) and we don't need to remove the `"`s:

```
$ awk -F, '{a[NR]=$2} NR>2{print $0,a[1],a[2]}' OFS=, InputFile.csv
1, abc, xyz,pq,11,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,"1-28-22 3:47"
2, def, xyz,rs,22,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,"1-28-22 3:47"
3, ghi, xyz,tu,33,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,"1-28-22 3:47"
4, jkl, xyz,vw,44,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,"1-28-22 3:47"
5, mno, xyz,xy,55,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,"1-28-22 3:47"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ahhh, that two lines make a difference. Try

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 {FN = $2} NR==2 {DT = $2} NR>2{print $0, FN, DT}' OFS=, InputFile.csv
1, abc, xyz,pq,11,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,"1-28-22 3:47"
2, def, xyz,rs,22,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,"1-28-22 3:47"
3, ghi, xyz,tu,33,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,"1-28-22 3:47"
4, jkl, xyz,vw,44,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,"1-28-22 3:47"
5, mno, xyz,xy,55,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,"1-28-22 3:47"
```

Comment: Those all-caps variable names are killin' me. I really thought `FN` was the builtin variable name `NF` for a minute....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to capture the values from the first two lines into shell variables as `awk` will do all the work for you.

```
awk -F, '
    BEGIN { OFS=FS }                                       # Output separator is same as input separator
    NR==1 { inputFile=$2 }                                 # Input File
    NR==2 { dtReceived=$2; gsub("\"", "", dtReceived) }    # Date Received, without surrounding double quotes
    NR>2 { print $0, inputFile, dtReceived }               # Copy through every line appending two new fields
' InputFile.csv > OutputFile.csv
```

Here, we have a four line `awk` program. You can put it all on one line but remove the `#` comment sections if you do so. However, consider which one will be more readable when you come back to it in a few weeks (or months) time.

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NR==1{inputFile=$2} NR==2{dtReceived=$2;gsub("\"","",dtReceived)} NR>2{print $0,inputFile,dtReceived}' InputFile.csv > OutputFile.csv
```

Notice that if this is a CSV file then removing the double quotes is unnecessary. But as your desired output file omitted them I've stripped them here too.

Output

```
1, abc, xyz,pq,11,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
2, def, xyz,rs,22,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
3, ghi, xyz,tu,33,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
4, jkl, xyz,vw,44,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
5, mno, xyz,xy,55,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` :

```
sed -n '1{N;s/^"[^"]*",//;s/,*\n"[^"]*","/,/;s/",*//;h;d};G;s/\n/,/p' inputFile.csv
```

Grab the first two lines, cut off the meaning less part and save it to the hold space. Then print each line, till the end, sticked to the `Hold space` saved before.

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('filename','r')
fin_lines=k.readlines()
firslin=fin_lines[0].strip().split(':')[-1]
firsli_conte=firslin.replace('"','').replace(",","")
secondlin=fin_lines[1].strip().split(",")[1].replace('"','')
for test in fin_lines[2:]:
    print test.strip()+","+firsli_conte+","+secondlin






firs=$(awk -F ":" 'NR==1{gsub(/[",]/,"",$NF);print $NF}' filename )

sec=$(awk -F ":" 'NR==2{gsub(/[",]/,"",$2);gsub(/[",]/,"",$3);print $2":"$3}' filename )

awk -v firs="$firs" -v sec="$sec" 'NR>2{print $0","firs","sec}' filename

output
1, abc, xyz,pq,11,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
2, def, xyz,rs,22,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
3, ghi, xyz,tu,33,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
4, jkl, xyz,vw,44,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
5, mno, xyz,xy,55,AB-ABCDE.20220128.02064600,1-28-22 3:47
```