# how to merge and amend columns of two files

Tags: awk, files, join, merge

I need to merge two files based on the 1st and 2nd columns. I need to add the difference between 3rd and 4th columns and add TOTAL rows per type of 2nd column. Here are the two input files:

File 1:

```
VALIDATION_DATA_DBF           DELETE  226  6.4
TXT_DBF                       DELETE  80   0.15
DEFAULT_PROFILE               SELECT  45   1.2
TRAINING_DBF                  SELECT  130  5.25
TESTING_DBF                   SELECT  5    0.001
WARNING_DBF                   UPDATE  8    0.055
WARNING_DBF                   INSERT  5    2.4
```

File 2:

```
VALIDATION_DATA_DBF           DELETE  200  7.4
TXT_DBF                       DELETE  70   1.15
DEFAULT_PROFILE               SELECT  40   0.2
TRAINING_DBF                  SELECT  135  7.25
TESTING_DBF                   SELECT  7    0.009
PERF_DBF                      SELECT  10   0.004
WARNING_DBF                   UPDATE  2    1.055
```

The merged output file should be as shown below:

```
TABLE                TYPE    COUNT1 COUNT2 DIFF_COUNT TIME1 TIME2 DIFF_TIME
VALIDATION_DATA_DBF  DELETE  226    200    26         6.4    7.4    -1
TXT_DBF              DELETE  80     70     10         0.15   1.15   -1
TOTAL                DELETE  306    270    36         6.55   8.55   -2
DEFAULT_PROFILE      SELECT  45     40     5          1.2    0.2     1   
TRAINING_DBF         SELECT  130    135    -5         5.25   7.25   -2
TESTING_DBF          SELECT  5      7      -2         0.001  0.009  -0.008
PERF_DBF             SELECT  0      10     -10        0      0.004  -0.004
TOTAL                SELECT  180    192    -12        6.451  7.463  -1.012 
WARNING_DBF          UPDATE  8      2      6          0.055  1.055  -1
TOTAL                UPDATE  8      2      6          0.055  1.055  -1
WARNING_DBF          INSERT  5      0      5          2.4    0      2.4
TOTAL                INSERT  5      0      5          2.4    0      2.4
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Also, this question is very unclear so it is uncertain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings I'm trying to compare 2 trace files to get the comparison results at the end with total per Type of action

Comment: the summary box of the question is just the place for writing the title of the question not to writing whole context of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays and ARGIND:

```
awk '
    {
        counts[$2][$1][ARGIND] = $3
        times[$2][$1][ARGIND] = $4
    }
    END {
        print "TABLE", "TYPE", \
            "COUNT1", "COUNT2", "DIFF_COUNT", \
            "TIME1", "TIME2", "DIFF_TIME"
    
        for ( type in counts ) {
            delete totCounts
            delete totTimes
            for ( table in counts[type] ) {
                print table, type,                                   \
                    counts[type][table][1]+0,                        \
                    counts[type][table][2]+0,                        \
                    counts[type][table][1] - counts[type][table][2], \
                    times[type][table][1]+0,                         \
                    times[type][table][2]+0,                         \
                    times[type][table][1] - times[type][table][2]
    
                totCounts[1] += counts[type][table][1]
                totCounts[2] += counts[type][table][2]
                totTimes[1]  += times[type][table][1]
                totTimes[2]  += times[type][table][2]
            }
            print "TOTAL", type, \
                totCounts[1], totCounts[2], totCounts[1] - totCounts[2], \
                totTimes[1],  totTimes[2],  totTimes[1]  - totTimes[2]
        }
    }
' file1 file2 | column -t
TABLE                TYPE    COUNT1  COUNT2  DIFF_COUNT  TIME1  TIME2  DIFF_TIME
VALIDATION_DATA_DBF  DELETE  226     200     26          6.4    7.4    -1
TXT_DBF              DELETE  80      70      10          0.15   1.15   -1
TOTAL                DELETE  306     270     36          6.55   8.55   -2
WARNING_DBF          UPDATE  8       2       6           0.055  1.055  -1
TOTAL                UPDATE  8       2       6           0.055  1.055  -1
WARNING_DBF          INSERT  5       0       5           2.4    0      2.4
TOTAL                INSERT  5       0       5           2.4    0      2.4
PERF_DBF             SELECT  0       10      -10         0      0.004  -0.004
TESTING_DBF          SELECT  5       7       -2          0.001  0.009  -0.008
TRAINING_DBF         SELECT  130     135     -5          5.25   7.25   -2
DEFAULT_PROFILE      SELECT  45      40      5           1.2    0.2    1
TOTAL                SELECT  180     192     -12         6.451  7.463  -1.012
```

Comment: it is working perfectly but is there a way to have it in 1 single command line?

Comment: Sure, remove the ```\<newline>```s and replace the unescaped newlines with semi-colons, but why on earth would you want to do that? You're not planning to type that on your terminal every time you want to do it are you?

Comment: I'm writing 1 bash script, I don't want to call another tst.awk file.

Comment: With any awk script you can either save it in a file and call is as `awk -f scriptfile inputfile` as I'm doing in my answer or you can include it inline as `awk 'script' inputfile`. You don't need to cram the script into 1 line to do either thing. I updated my answer to use the `awk 'script' inputfile` way of calling it, just use it exactly like that in your shell script.

Comment: it is working perfectly now in 1 single script without pointing to any external file :)
Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the counts and times by file, Table, and Type. Best use two arrays, plus one to attach Table to Type. In the END section, the evaluation is done; not much logics, but a heap of text to type in... Try

```
awk '
FNR == 1        {FN++
                }
                {CNT[FN,$1,$2] = $3
                 TIM[FN,$1,$2] = $4
                 if (!index(TYP[$2], $1)) TYP[$2] = TYP[$2] $1 FS
                }
END             {print "TABLE               TYPE    COUNT1 COUNT2 DIFF_COUNT  TIME1 TIME2 DIFF_TIME"
                 for (t in TYP) {TC1 = TC2 = TDF = TT1 = TT2 = TTF = 0
                                 for (m=split(TYP[t], T); m; m--)       {TBL = T[m]
                                                                         IX1 = 1 SUBSEP TBL SUBSEP t
                                                                         IX2 = 2 SUBSEP TBL SUBSEP t
                                                                         printf "%-20s%-8s%-7d%-7d%-10d  %-6g%-6g%-6g\n", TBL, t, CNT[IX1]+0, CNT[IX2]+0, CNT[
                                                                         TC1 += CNT[IX1]
                                                                         TC2 += CNT[IX2]
                                                                         TDF += CNT[IX1] - CNT[IX2]
                                                                         TT1 += TIM[IX1]
                                                                         TT2 += TIM[IX2]
                                                                         TTF += TIM[IX1] - TIM[IX2]
                                                                        }
                                 printf "%-20s%-8s%-7d%-7d%-10d  %-6g%-6g%-6g \n",  "TOTAL", t, TC1, TC2, TDF, TT1, TT2, TTF
                                }
                }
' OFS="\t" file[12]

TABLE               TYPE    COUNT1 COUNT2 DIFF_COUNT  TIME1 TIME2 DIFF_TIME
TXT_DBF             DELETE  80     70     10          0.15  1.15  -1    
VALIDATION_DATA_DBF DELETE  226    200    26          6.4   7.4   -1    
TOTAL               DELETE  306    270    36          6.55  8.55  -2     
WARNING_DBF         INSERT  5      0      5           2.4   0     2.4   
TOTAL               INSERT  5      0      5           2.4   0     2.4    
PERF_DBF            SELECT  0      10     -10         0     0.004 -0.004
TESTING_DBF         SELECT  5      7      -2          0.001 0.009 -0.008
TRAINING_DBF        SELECT  130    135    -5          5.25  7.25  -2    
DEFAULT_PROFILE     SELECT  45     40     5           1.2   0.2   1     
TOTAL               SELECT  180    192    -12         6.451 7.463 -1.012 
WARNING_DBF         UPDATE  8      2      6           0.055 1.055 -1    
TOTAL               UPDATE  8      2      6           0.055 1.055 -1
```

Comment: how to pass the input files? the command is giving me a lot of errors when launched. How to use it through the command line?

Comment: you are still using all upper case variables name it's [recommended not to use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691853/i-want-to-add-awk-command-result-to-end-of-each-rows-in-a-csv-file/691865#comment1308423_691865)