# Concatenating some strings in some specific lines of multiple text files into a single file with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have ~100 text files named *.txt in the following form:

```
=========================================================
 rho_center   e_center    Mass      Mass_0      R_e
 1.0000e-03 1.1236e-03 1.5379e+00 1.6522e+00 1.0734e+01
     J         T/W       Omega   Omega_Kepler axes_ratio
 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 3.5265e-02 1.0000e+00
    J/M^2
 0.0000e+00
=========================================================
yy| rhoc  =   1.00000000e-03 ;
yy| rp_re =   1.00000000e+00 ;
yy| A_diff=   1.00000000e+00 ;
yy| Re    =   1.07336268e+01 ;
yy| M0    =   1.65219709e+00 ;
yy| M     =   1.53786062e+00 ;
yy| W     =   2.10814073e-01 ;
yy| T     =   0.00000000e+00 ;
yy| J     =   0.00000000e+00 ;
yy| beta  =   0.00000000e+00 ;
yy| M_R   =   1.43275023e-01 ;
  | === periods in msecs ==========
yy| Pa    =              inf ;
yy| Pe    =              inf ;
yy| td    =   8.46677695e-01 ;
yy| PK    =   8.77582921e-01 ;
yy| MDIV = 301 ; SDIV = 601;
```

I want to concatenate the values of rhoc and M in a single text file, like this:

```
rhoc M
0.001 1.537
...    ...
0.004 2.328
```

I am a layman of bash and I try to use awk to do it but failed. How to write the bash script to do this job?

Comment: awk should be a good tool for this. What did you try and what output did you get?

Comment: see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

With `gawk`, assuming there's only one `rhoc`/`M` per file:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN {print "rhoc M"}
  BEGINFILE {delete field}
  $3 == "=" {field[$2] = $4}
  ENDFILE {
    if (("rhoc" in field) && ("M" in field))
      print field["rhoc"], field["M"]
  }' ./*.txt
```

That will process the files in the lexicographical order of they names. If using `zsh`, replace `./*.txt` with `./*.txt(n)` so that the order be numeric (so `file2.txt` comes *before* `file10.txt` for instance).

Answer (score 0):

For non-gawk use (tested on linux (mawk) and FreeBSD), try

```
LC_ALL=C awk -vHD="rhoc M" '
BEGIN           {for (MX=m=split(HD, IX); m; m--) FLDS[IX[m]]
                 print HD
                }
FNR == 1        {CNT++
                }               
$2 in FLDS      {OUT[$2, CNT] = $4+0
                }
END             {for (i=1; i<=CNT; i++) {for(j=1; j<=MX; j++) printf "%.6g%s", OUT[IX[j],i], (j==MX?ORS:OFS)}
                }
'  *.txt
rhoc M
0.001 1.53786
```

It will allow you to extend your data extraction by simply extending the HD variable upfront.
It counts up the input files, collects the desired data per file into the OUT array, and in the END section prints all out in the order of the files encountered.

Comment: [you are still keep using all uppercase variables name!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691916/how-to-merge-and-amend-columns-of-two-files/691924#comment1308589_691924) why?

Answer (score 0):

`sed` :

```
sed -n '/rhoc/{s/^yy| rhoc *= *\([0-9.e+-]*\) *;/\1/;h;};/ M /{s/^yy| M *= *\([0-9.e+-]*\) *;/\1/;x;G;s/\n/ /p}' sample
```

in a multiline fashion :

```
sed -n '
    /rhoc/{
        s/^yy| rhoc *= *\([0-9.e+-]*\) *;/\1/
        h
    }
    / M /{
        s/^yy| M *= *\([0-9.e+-]*\) *;/\1/
        x;G;s/\n/ /p
    }
' sample
```